# Imagine that you have plane and $n$ groups of straight lines

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

In $i$-th group there are $a_i$ parallel straight lines and for every two groups it is true that their representatives are not parallel.

What is number of parts that plane can be split by these straight lines?

IMPORTANT: you can assume that three straight lines can't intersect in one point.

I, honestly, don't know how to approach this. When I try to think of it I struggle with figuring out how to generalize different relative positions.

Comment: A particular case $a_1=4,a_2=a_3=...=1$ has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1261459).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $a_1$ vertical lines & $a_2$ horizontal lines. This will give $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)$ regions.

Now run a line diagonally, this will give $a_1+a_2+1$ new regions, and if we run $a_3$ such parallel lines that will give $a_3(a_1+a_2+1)$. Add this on ... $1+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3 $ regions.

The induction now becomes obvious ? ... in general there are $1 + \sum a_i + \sum_{i > j } a_i a_j$ regions.

Comment: Can you please explain this transition: "Add this on ... $1+a_1+a$..."?

Comment: @math-traveler Ooops, typo ... thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Can you, please, give an example what happens when we have $a_4$?

Comment: This will cross the $a_1+a_2+a_3$ lines and create $a_1+a_2+a_3+1$ new regions ...

Comment: [+1] It is to be noted that if all the $a_1$ are equal to one, we retrieve the classical formula : $1+n+\frac12 n(n-1)=1+\frac12 n(n+1)$ ([lazy caterer sequence](https://oeis.org/A000124/internal)).